# Create a new object that excludes specified keys

Tags: javascript, performance

I have 2 data structures with me in JS. One is an array say of **length N**. Let's consider `N = 4`.

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

The second one is an object:

```
const obj = {
  a: 0,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  z: 5
};
```

I wrote a code in Javascript, to create a new object out of `obj` which should not contain the keys which are not present in the array `arr`. As of now, the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of the code is \$O(n*n)\$ i.e., \$O(4*4)\$.

```
standardizeFilter(queryParams: any, inputType: Array<string>) {
  const filter = {};

  for (const key of Object.keys(queryParams)) {
    if (inputType.indexOf(key) > -1) {
      filter[key] = this.parseValues(queryParams[key]);
    }
  }
  return filter;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a much optimal way to convert this \$O(n²)\$ to \$O(n)\$.

Comment: Loop over the array, not the object keys.

Comment: A critique about your terminology: saying "O(4*4)" is wrong.

Comment: code review requires the full code, not just stub. Please provide the full code of the class or at least the part that has `parseValues`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a short review;

- Naming

  - `standardizeFilter` is too specific/specialized, perhaps `standardizeObject`?
  - `queryParams` also seems a very specific name, whereas the functionality is very general, I would just call it `keys`
  - `inputType` is not a type, it's an object, I would propose `source`
- For each `key` you perform both a `indexOf` and a `[]` access, you can drop the `indexOf`

I would propose something like this:

```
function standardizeObject(source, keys){

  const o = {};

  for(const key of keys){
    const value = source[key];
    if(value !== undefined){
      o[key] =  this.parseValues(value);
    }
  } 

  return o;
}
```